# Redirecting a page into the same tabbed window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, tabs

I have a problem , I am quite new to this whole coding in cross languages , basically when I click on a row index in my GridView it then opens a new tab and brings in the results in that window ( The new one that has just opened ) and I know this is from using the `Window.Open` but I am wondering is there a function that I can use to just open my results in the actual same window from where it is being clicked? something like `Window.Open` `<Open in same window>`? My code is below.

`Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
            e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
            Dim Index As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex
            e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("OnClick") = "window.open('MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=" + GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID").ToString + "');"
        End If
    End Sub`

Please make your answers Clear as possible for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of window.open() use window.location.href like the following

```
 window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: So how would this look being converted from window.open('MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=" + GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID").ToString + "'); ?

Comment: window.location.href='MachineSweepLite.aspx?AreaID=' + GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID").ToString;

Comment: are u adding this line in clientscriptmanager or directly in javascript?